# how to detect facebook canvas app location

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, canvas, facebook-apps

i am trying to detect the location entry point of a user when accessing my app.

if the user comes to apps.facebook.com/foobar for the first time then they have a signed_request and i can set a session variable. but now the session variable says they are located in the canvas app. so if they go to foobar.com they will be treated as if they are in the canvas apps, and i want to avoid that. i am trying to find a way to check with 100% certainty every time they come to the app that they are in the facebook canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `JavaScript`, Try this:

```
// Store session for is located in the canvas app
var isLocatedInCanvas = <?php echo isset($_SESSION['isLocatedInCanvas']) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>;
// Check if app is not in an iframe and isLocatedInCanvas is true
if (window.location == top.window.location && isLocatedInCanvas) {
    // Now redirect the user to clear session page and unset or clear isLocatedInCanvas value
    window.location = 'clear-session.php';
    // After clearing the session send the user to home page (foobar.com)
}
```